# Number of distinct functions such that there does not exist any $i\in A$ such that $f(i)=i+1$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Question: **"How many distinct functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are there, from the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to itself, such that there does not exist any $i\in A$ such that $f(i)=i+1$?**

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to go about it.

There are $\vert A\vert^{\vert A\vert}=5^5$ distinct functions, $f:A\to A$, mapping A to A. From these, there are $4$ distinct functions, such that $f(i)=i+1$. ($f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=4$ and $f(4)=5$).

So, there are $5^5 -4$ distinct functions with the condition required by the question.

Comment: It says "there does not exist **any** $i \in A$ such that $f(i) = i+1$". And even with $f(1) = 2$ there are more than $4$ mappings such that for all those mappings, $1$ is mapped to $2$. Why do you think there are only $4$ such functions?

Comment: Your count is incorrect because you have to avoid functions like $f(i)=i$ for all $i \neq 2$ and $f(2)=3$. Because the condition is $\not\exists \, i$.

Comment: $1$ can be mapped to $4$ possible values, similarly $2,3,4$ can be mapped to $4$ values, $5$ can be mapped to $5$ values ... so there are $5 \times 4^4$ such maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1$ can be mapped to $4$ possible values, similarly $2,3,4$ can be mapped to $4$ values, $5$ can be mapped to $5$ values ... so there are $5 \times 4^4$ such maps.